# Shuffle TFRecordDataset files but not samples inside the files

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have data generated and saved into multiple tfrecord files that are then loaded into a TFRecordDataset. **How can I shuffle this dataset by files?** That is, I want to keep the order of samples *inside* the files but only randomize the order in which the files are loaded when creating a batched dataset. Consider the following example:

**Data**

```
file_1
  file_1_s1
  file_1_s2
  file_1_s3


file_2
  file_2_s1
  file_2_s2
  file_2_s3


file_3
  file_3_s1
  file_3_s2
  file_3_s3
```

**Legal sample orderings**

```
file_1_s2, file_1_s2, file_1_s3, file_3_s1, file_3_s2, file_3_s3, file_2_s1, file_2_s2, file_2_s3
file_3_s1, file_3_s2, file_3_s3, file_2_s1, file_2_s2, file_2_s3, file_1_s2, file_1_s2, file_1_s3
```

**Illegal sample orderings**

```
file_1_s2, file_1_s3, file_3_s3, file_2_s1, file_2_s2, file_1_s2, file_3_s2, file_3_s1, file_2_s3
file_3_s1, file_2_s1, file_3_s3, file_2_s2, file_2_s3, file_1_s2, file_1_s2, file_1_s3, file_3_s2
```

In the illegal examples, the samples of one file do not occur together or in order anymore.

Comment: why not just randomly sort the python list of tfrecord filenames before you send it to tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: Because I want to shuffle every epoch. So I would need to recreate the dataset every time. @gobrewers14

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to shuffle your `TFRecord` files as below.

```
filepaths = ["data.tfrecords","data1.tfrecords","data2.tfrecords","data3.tfrecords"]

filepath_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filepaths, seed=42)

print(filepath_dataset)
```

> `<ShuffleDataset shapes: (), types: tf.string>`

```
for file in filepath_dataset:
  print(file)
```

**Shuffled dataset:**

```
tf.Tensor(b'./data1.tfrecords', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./data3.tfrecords', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./data2.tfrecords', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./data.tfrecords', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

`list_files` takes 3 arguments.
 **file:** *A string, a list of strings, or a tf.Tensor of string type (scalar or vector), representing the filename glob (i.e. shell wildcard) pattern(s) that will be matched.*
**shuffle:** *Default is set to True which shuffles files randomly.*
**seed :** *(Optional.) A tf.int64 scalar tf.Tensor, representing the random seed that will be used to create the distribution.*

Returns A Dataset of strings corresponding to file names.

Hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!